# JavaScript function pointer problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

just starting out with JavaScript and jQuery, and i have this problem:

```
foo(validation);

function foo(func) {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  // do some other stuff
  func("foobar" + time);
}

function validation(elementName) {
  // do stuff
}
```

but when i call function foo with the validation function pointer, i would also like to pass in the string "foobar" at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just invoke another (anonym) function:

```
foo(function() {
  validation('foobar');
});
```

By the way, there are no real "pointers" in ECMAscript, it's a reference tho. I guess you're doing it this way for educational reasons (passing a funarg = `functional argument`) into a high-order function, but you can simplify the whole thing into:

```
validation('foobar' + (+new Date()));
```

Comment: I think you should should show how you'd pass the `time` to the validation method.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
function foo(str, func) {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    // do some other stuff
    func(str + time);
}
function validation(elementName) {
  // do stuff
}
foo("foobar", validation);
```

Answer (score 1):

ah i see... you shouldn't use this may one say but try:

```
eval("func(\"foobar"+time+"\")");
```

Comment: it's considered as very bad practice to use `eval()`, It's creating a new scope (context) which is kinda slow'ish, plus it's always a security risk to evaluate code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is that flexible, here's another way using currying.

```
function createFoo(string) {
    return function(aFunction) {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        // ..
        aFunction(string + time);
    };
}

var foobar = createFoo("foobar");
foobar(validation);
```

Answer (score 1):

what about if you send as foo parameters the function name and an array of arguments for that function?

`function foo(func,funcArgs){
   func.apply({},[new Date().getTime()].concat(funcArgs));
}
function validate(arguments){
}
//then you could pass anything to the validate "pointer"
foo(validate,[argument1,argument2,/*...*/argumentn]);`